# Unicode null and JSON

Tags: java, javascript, json, unicode, encoding

I have a JSON object that when serialized gets the null Unicode character. (The character is coming from a database.) I can replace the character through java but it seems slightly hackish to look for a specific character to fix. So I'm wondering if there's a way I can do it by just changing the encoding. It's currently being encoded using UTF-8. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're right, that would be a hack.  Character encoding issues are hard to track down even when you have all the material in front of you.  You have supplied pretty much 0 material.  Maybe post a [SCCE](http://sscce.org/) Java along with a .sql file that creates the db, table, column, sample data, etc.  What libs and db product you are using?  UTF8 is not supposed to have embedded null chars, ever.

Comment: Have you looked into [UTF-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7)?

Comment: Why can't you sanitize the data in your DB? I wouldn't think you actually want the null character in there.

Comment: if the character is coming from the database, sanitize your data in the database, or have the database access layer do the sanitization for you. This is not something you fix at the end, this needs a fix at the source.

Comment: What is the problem with having a U+0000 NULL character? They are legal in JSON (encoded as `\u0000`) and Java strings. If you have to clean your data because it has errors like a stray NULL in then that's something you should do after having parsed the strings; it's not really anything to do with Unicode character encodings. If you are talking about *every second* character being a NULL then that *is* an encoding problem, you've interpreted UTF-16 as ASCII somewhere.

Comment: If you don't have control over the database, the hack is appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately, as noted by Joe Coder, we don't have control over the database, so we're greatly limited in that regards. I can sanitize it upon retrieval from the database but that seems crazy since nearly every query/class would need to change to account for a field that could potentially contain a null unicode.
The problem that we encounter isn't actually in the Java or JSON layers, but in the various apps that consume our data services. Their various languages and OS's can't handle the null unicode.

Comment: We're using google's GSON to do the serialization/conversion. So is there anything in there that could help or any other encoding option that would do a "mass" fix for all strings that could contain a null unicode character?